# ReactJs - How to get updated state while inside a thunk promise

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on an application where prior to sending the data to the server we check if the fields are empty and fill them with dummy data.

State before sending data to server:

```
state = {
  title: '',
  body: ''
}
```

my dispatch function:

```
this.props.dispatch((dispatch) => {
  dispatch(initializeProcessForm());
  dispatch(processForm(state));
});
```

Inside `initializeProcessForm` I check if the fields are blank and fill them appropriately, but considering we should not **mutate the state**, I have to make a new state object and return.

**Here, I loose the reference** to the current (new state after function completes) and when **dispatch(processForm(state))** submits to the server, it still holds the old data with blank fields.

How can I get around this problem without mutating the state react way?

The only way I can access the new state is once I am in inside the reducer but the API call happens inside the Action before going to the reducer when I am handling success or rejection of the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second argument passed to your thunks by redux-thunk is getState

```
this.props.dispatch((dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(initializeProcessForm());
  const updatedState = getState();
  dispatch(processForm(updatedState));
});
```